# Illegal State Exception error-Android

Tags: android, exception, styles

Strangely I get this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat 
theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I searched about this over the net but none of the solutions helped me.

This is my styles.xml file.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
 </style>
```

Part of the manifest file is.

```
 <application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This exception is happening after adding an alert dialog code.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's me",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PopupMenu homepopup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), view);
            MenuInflater inflater = homepopup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, homepopup.getMenu());

            homepopup.show();

            homepopup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getApplicationContext());

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    InvitationBoard.this.finish();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build the dialog, use an activity context not the application context:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getApplicationContext());
```

For example, if your code is in an activity:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```